# Corresponding a list with another list

Tags: excel, list, excel-formula

I have a list of Store IDs (in one column) with their corresponding opening dates (in the other column). On the 3rd column I have a list another list of Store IDs but there are duplicates. I want to transfer the opening dates to the 4th column with corresponding Store ID.

[image]

I added  a screen shot of it. I'm pretty sure it's simple to do but I fon't how to phrase the question w/o explaining. Thank you in Advance!

Comment: use `Vlookup`   ....

Answer (score 0):

In cell D2 enter the formula:

```
=VLookup(C2,A:B,2,False)
```

Then drag-copy the formula to fill in the values.